# H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator() - Prediction Error

Tags: java, python, glm, h2o

I am trying to predict test times in a Kaggle comp using the H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator function. The model trains normally in line 3 and the metrics are all reasonable. However when I come to the predict step I get an error despite the test data frame matching the train data frame.

Has anyone seen this error before?

```
 h2o_glm = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator()

 h2o_glm.train(training_frame=train_h2o,y='y')

 h2o_glm_predictions = h2o_glm.predict(test_data=test_h2o).as_data_frame()

 test_pred = pd.read_csv('test.csv')[['ID']]
 test_pred['y'] = h2o_glm_predictions
 test_pred.to_csv('h2o_glm_predictions.csv',index=False)
```

glm Model Build progress: |███████████████████████████████████████████████| 100%

```
glm prediction progress: | (failed)

OSError Traceback (most recent call last) in () 3 h2o_glm.train(training_frame=train_h2o,y='y') 4 ----> 5 h2o_glm_predictions = h2o_glm.predict(test_data=test_h2o).as_data_frame() 6 7 test_pred = pd.read_csv('test.csv')[['ID']]

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/model/model_base.py in predict(self, test_data) 130 j = H2OJob(h2o.api("POST /4/Predictions/models/%s/frames/%s" % (self.model_id, test_data.frame_id)), 131 self._model_json["algo"] + " prediction") --> 132 j.poll() 133 return h2o.get_frame(j.dest_key) 134

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/job.py in poll(self) 71 if (isinstance(self.job, dict)) and ("stacktrace" in list(self.job)): 72 raise EnvironmentError("Job with key {} failed with an exception: {}\nstacktrace: " ---> 73 "\n{}".format(self.job_key, self.exception, self.job["stacktrace"])) 74 else: 75 raise EnvironmentError("Job with key %s failed with an exception: %s" % (self.job_key, self.exception))
```

> OSError: Job with key
>   $03017f00000132d4ffffffff$_868312f4c32f683871930a1145c1476a failed
>   with an exception: DistributedException from /127.0.0.1:54321: 'null',
>   caused by java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException stacktrace:
>   DistributedException from /127.0.0.1:54321: 'null', caused by
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at
>   water.MRTask.getResult(MRTask.java:478) at
>   water.MRTask.getResult(MRTask.java:486) at
>   water.MRTask.doAll(MRTask.java:390) at
>   water.MRTask.doAll(MRTask.java:396) at
>   hex.glm.GLMModel.predictScoreImpl(GLMModel.java:1215) at
>   hex.Model.score(Model.java:1077) at
>   water.api.ModelMetricsHandler$1.compute2(ModelMetricsHandler.java:351)
>   at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1349) at
>   jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468) at
>   jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263) at
>   jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974) at
>   jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477) at
>   jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: This looks like the same error I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901421/h2o-predictions-sometimes-fail-when-response-variable-not-present-in-test-set As a workaround, try adding a fake response column (e.g. add a constant column 'y' to test_data)

Comment: This worked straight away - thank you! Hopefully this bug gets fixed in a later update. Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me which version of H2O this is so I can track that in the bug report?  Thx.

Comment: It is H2O version 3.12.0.1. I am also having a problem with xgboost in H2o 3.12.0.1 when I try to perform a grid search with a h2o xgboost estimator. Is this a known problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments above, the current solution is to add a response column (with fake data if it doesn't exist) to the `test_data` frame.  However, this is a bug that should be fixed.  The JIRA is [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4659).

Comment: I can confirm this bug also exists in R (both h2o 3.10.3.3 and 3.12.0.1) and that it does not seem to be GLM specific, but rather something to do with explicit one hot encoding - see the question I linked to in the comments.